# bash function parameter construction ${1,,}

Tags: bash, function, parameters, parameter-passing

In a script I found, I see this construction:

```
is_true() {
  local var=${1,,} 
  ...
```

As I understand it is some kind of parameter passing. $1,$2,$# I understand but what ${1,,} stands for?

Comment: `man bash`,`/,,`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ( `${1,,}`) is called "Parameter Expansion" available in bash version 4+ . Here it is used to change the case of the string stored in the variable, In this case first argument to the script.

Some examples: **Lower case** conversion.

```
x='HellO'
echo ${x}
HellO
echo ${x,,}
hello
```

To convert `$x` into **upper case**.

```
echo ${x^^}
HELLO
```

To **invert** the case:

```
x='Hey there'
echo ${x~~}
hEY THERE
```